# Flutter - How to set playback timer in audio_service?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, audio-service

I am using `audio_service` package for playing background audio.Now, I want to stop the currently playing playlist or audio after certain time set by the user. Is there any better approach of doing this?

I have implemented the code provided in the [example](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/minor/audio_service/example/lib/example_playlist.dart) folder by the author.